# How to make a button that will uncheck all checkboxes and changes the background color of the divs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have following code: [jiddle.com](https://jsfiddle.net/xDavId/3va1p7hw/)

There are two checkboxes with a picture and a label in a div. When the checkbox is selected the div changes the background color to orange.

Now i have added a button with which i can uncheck all checkboxes but the background color does not change back to white. Does anyone now where is my mistake?

```js
function uncheckAll() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").prop("checked", false)
}
$('#aufheben_button').on('click', uncheckAll)
    
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked", true)){
       $(this).parent().addClass("changeBackground"); 
        }
    else{
       $(this).parent().removeClass("changeBackground");
       $('#aufheben_button').parent().removeClass("changeBackground");  
        }
    });
```

```css
li{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 160px;
    height: 130px;
    margin: 0 0 3px 0;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
}
.app_name{
  
    font-size: calc(10px + 0.4vw);
}
label{
    display: block;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
.picture{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px 
}

/* Customize the label (the container) */
.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  /* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
  .container input {
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
  
  /* Create a custom checkbox */
  .checkmark {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
  }
  
  /* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
  .container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  
  /* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
  .container input:checked ~ .checkmark  {
    background-color: #FD9B08;
  }

  /* Ändern des Hintergrunds bei der Groupbox */
  .isChecked {
    background-color: #FD9B08;
  }
  
  /* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
  .checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
  }
  
  /* Show the checkmark when checked */
  .container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
  }
  
  /* Style the checkmark/indicator */
  .container .checkmark:after {
    left: 9px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  .changeBackground{
    background-color: #FD9B08;
  }
 
  .div_groupbox{
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: auto;
  }
  .div_groupbox:hover{
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script><html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="aufheben" id="aufheben_button">unselect checkmarks</button>
    
    <ul>
        <li class="background_li">
            <div class="div_groupbox">               
                <label class="container">
                    <img id="Firefox" src="Bilder/Test1.png" class="picture"> 
                    <div class="app_name">Test1</div><input type="checkbox" name="acs" value="Test1"> 
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>                         
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="div_groupbox">
                <label class="container">
                    <img src="Bilder/Test2.png" class="picture">
                    <div class="app_name">Test2</div><input type="checkbox" name="acs" value="Test2">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code should be included (embedded) in your question.

Comment: My bad have added the code into the question :)

Comment: you do not remove the class : try `function uncheckAll() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").prop("checked", false)
  $("input[type='checkbox']").parent().removeClass("changeBackground");
}`

Comment: thank you very much that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this to the uncheckAll function:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").prop("checked", false);
$("input[type='checkbox']").parent().removeClass("changeBackground");
```

And add a `onclick="uncheckAll()"` to the button.

Answer (score 0):

The change event handler will not be executed with this code:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").prop("checked", false);
```

If you want to execute whatever is in the change-event handler, then trigger the click event, which will toggle the checkbox and execute any event handlers that would result from that:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").trigger("click");
```